# минимальный элемент массива python

Tags: python

Нужно найти минимальный элемент массива, введенного с консоли, при этом не используя функцию min

```
massiv = []
dlina = int(input())
for y in range(0, dlina):
    massiv.append(int(input()))
for i in range(0, len(massiv)):
    min = massiv[0]
    if massiv[i] <= min:
        min = massiv[i]
print(min)
```

Не могу понять, почему выводит правильный ответ через раз.

Comment: вынести инициализацию min за цикл, у тебя же затирается значение минимума.

Answer (score 2):

Причина в том, что вы каждую итерацию цикла перезаписываете `min` нулевым элементом массива. Строку `min = massiv[0]` нужно вынести до цикла, вот так:

```
massiv = []
dlina = int(input())
for y in range(0, dlina):
    massiv.append(int(input()))
min = massiv[0]
for i in range(0, len(massiv)):
    if massiv[i] <= min:
        min = massiv[i]
print(min)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы постоянно устанавливаете минимум в цикле, что неправильно

Так же я бы заменил цикл

```
massiv = []
dlina = int(input())
for y in range(0, dlina):
    massiv.append(int(input()))
min_value = massiv[0]
for number in massiv:
    if number < min_value:
        min_value = number
print(min_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

во первых не очень хорошо использовать в качестве названия переменной название существующей функции

а ошибка в том, что присваивание минимального значения происходит внутри цикла, вынесите ее наружу цикла и все будет хорошо

кроме того зачем использовать `<=` при сравнении с минимальным значением, когда достаточно строгого меньше

ну и код поджать можно вот так еще:

```
data = [int(input()) for y in range(0, int(input()))]

value_min = data[0]
for value in data:
    value_min = value if value_min > value else value_min

print(value_min)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте отсортировал бы список и по индексу  доставал  значение

пример кода

```
massiv = []
dlina = int(input())
for y in range(0, dlina):
    massiv.append(int(input()))

massiv.sort()

print(massiv[0])
```

Comment: Какова сложность сортировки? А какова сложность одного прохода по списку?

Comment: я не знаю,если вы знаете то напишите мне будет интересно, код работает быстро и проще читается и условия соблюдены которые автор указал

Comment: плохо, что не знаете. А на тех пяти элементах, что вы вводите, разница конечно не будет видна. Введите пять миллионов значений и сравните.